How to get node fs to work in an Angular and Electron application
" The package "fs" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error."
I have run into an issue where I am trying to get node fs to read a local JSON file in an application using both Electron and Angular. Running the application through the browser works flawlessly, however, attempting to run the application in Electron causes the above error. Has anyone else run into this problem?
angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "password-manager": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/password-manager",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "password-manager:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "password-manager:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "password-manager",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng build --base-href ./ && set NODE_ENV=development && electron .",
    "serve": "ng serve --live-reload && set NODE_ENV=development && electron .",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:password-manager": "node dist/password-manager/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^18.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "esbuild": "^0.21.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "electron": "^30.1.0",
    "fs-extended": "^0.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

import { WebsiteAccount } from "./WebsiteAccount";
import * as fs from 'fs';
const Accounts = '../password-manager/src/data/accounts.json';

export class Data {

  accounts: WebsiteAccount[];

  constructor() {
    this.accounts = this.read();
    this.write();
  }
  
  private read() {
    var accounts: WebsiteAccount[] = [];


      var jsonString = fs.readFileSync(Accounts, 'utf-8');
      var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      var numAccounts = Object.keys(data).length;
      
      for (var i = 0; i < numAccounts; i++) {
          var newWebsite: WebsiteAccount = new WebsiteAccount(data[i].title, data[i].link, data[i].username, data[i].password, data[i].email, data[i].countryCode, data[i].areaCode, data[i].prefixCode, data[i].lineCode);
          accounts.push(newWebsite);
        }

      return accounts;
    
  }

  write() {
    const data = Object.assign({}, this.accounts);
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
    fs.writeFileSync(Accounts, dataString);
  }

  
}

I have tried using fs-extended, attempted setting angular to browser build mode, and have attempted manually setting the flags to esbuild.

Looks to me like you try to use fs from the renderer process.
As the documentation states: "the renderer has no direct access to require or other Node.js APIs. In order to directly include NPM modules in the renderer, you must use the same bundler toolchains (for example, webpack or parcel) that you use on the web." (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-renderer-process)
You should instead define the interaction with the file system in the main process and use the context bridge in order to expose it to the renderer process.
I recently did something similar in a small project using Angular and electron. Here is how I did it:
In electron main process:
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Add your window logic here

// Small function to write to the file system
ipcMain.handle("writeData", async (event, data, fileName) => {
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName, data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error writing data", error);
  }
})

// Small function to read from the file system
ipcMain.handle("readData", async (event, fileName) => {
  try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, "utf-8");
    return data.toString();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error retrieving user data", error);
  }
})

These are the basic functions to read and write anything anywhere in the file system. This happens in the main process which has access to the fs. We now need to make these functions available to the renderer process.
This is done through the context bridge (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge) which is defined in a preload script (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload)
To use a context bridge, we need to add the following line to our BrowserWindow definition (in electron main process):
BrowserWindow({
    // Add your specific window definition params
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"), // use a preload script
    }
})

In preload.js:
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
/*
This section provides an interface to read and write files to the user-data directory.
*/
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
  writeData: (data, fileName) => ipcRenderer.invoke("writeData", data, fileName),
  readData: (fileName) => ipcRenderer.invoke("readData", fileName)
});

The method name is pretty implicit, we make our functions available to the outside world. We now only need to use them:
In your Angular app, most likely your Data service (in the electron renderer process):
  /**
   * Write
   */
  storeToDisk(MyAmazingData) {
    window.electronAPI.writeData(
      JSON.stringify(MyAmazingData),
      "MyAmazingFile"
    );
  }

  /**
   * Read
   */
  loadFromDisk() {
    window.electronAPI
      .readData("MyAmazingFile")
      .then((data) => {
        // Handle reading
      });
  }

As a bonus to make electron.window.electronAPI typescript-compliant:
In electronAPI.d.ts:
// Declare electron API types to make electron code ts-compliant.
export type ElectronAPI = {
    writeData: (data: string, fileName: string) => Promise<void>,
    readData: (fileName: string) => Promise<string>,
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electronAPI: ElectronAPI
    initData: InitData
  }
}

This solution solved the issue for me and is relatively easy to use when properly setup. I would like to point out that I am a beginner with electron and there might be an easier way to perform this.
This solution works asynchronously, which is its only downside. The docs seem to imply that this is the proper way to use the context bridge:
⚠️ WARNING: Sending a synchronous message will block the whole renderer process until the reply is received, so use this method only as a last resort. It's much better to use the asynchronous version, invoke().

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendsyncchannel-args
